# 2 I2C and 1 UART are not working simultaneously in ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, uart, i2c, arduino-esp32

I have a project in which I have to monitor Acceleration of the subject, Location and Pulse + SpO2 of the subject. So, I've written this program to check data from MAX30100 Pulse Oxi sensor and MPU6050 Accelero and Gyroscope sensor using ESP32 -

This program works completely fine. No issues at all.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <Blynk.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

char auth[] = "*********************";   

// For Pulse sensor
PulseOximeter pox;
float BPM, SpO2;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

// For Accelerometer sensor
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
int16_t accelX, accelY, accelZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
float gForceX, gForceY, gForceZ,rotX, rotY, rotZ;

void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat Detected!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin("TP-Link", "**********");

  // Wait for wifi to be connected
  uint32_t notConnectedCounter = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Wifi connecting...");
      notConnectedCounter++;
      if(notConnectedCounter > 50) { // Reset board if not connected after 5s
          Serial.println("Resetting due to Wifi not connecting...");
          ESP.restart();
      }
  }
  Serial.print("Wifi connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  Blynk.begin(auth,"TP-Link_380B", "installation*500");
  Serial.println("Initializing Pulse Oximeter..");
 
    if (!pox.begin())
    {
         Serial.println("FAILED");
         for(;;);
    }
    else
    {
         Serial.println("SUCCESS");
         pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
    }
 
    // The default current for the IR LED is 50mA and it could be changed by uncommenting the following line.
        pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
        
  Wire1.begin(32,33,100000); 
  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire1.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire1.endTransmission(true);
}

void loop()
{
 
  // Reading data from Accelerometer sensor

  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire1.endTransmission(false);
  Wire1.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  accelX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  accelY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  accelZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  
  gyroX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  gyroY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  gyroZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();

  gForceX = (accelX-2050) / 16384.0;
  gForceY = (accelY-77) / 16384.0; 
  gForceZ = (accelZ-1947) / 16384.0;

  rotX = (gyroX+270) / 131.0;
  rotY = (gyroY-351) / 131.0; 
  rotZ = (gyroZ+136) / 131.0;

  // calculating Amplitute vactor for 3 axis
  float Raw_Amp = pow(pow(gForceX,2)+pow(gForceY,2)+pow(gForceZ,2),0.5);
  int Amp = Raw_Amp * 10;  // Mulitiplied by 10 bcz values are between 0 to 1
  int angleChange = pow(pow(rotX,2)+pow(rotY,2)+pow(rotZ,2),0.5);

  // Reading data from pulseoximeter sensor
  pox.update();
  BPM = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();

  // Uploading data to Blynk server AND printing data on serial monitor
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)
    {
      Blynk.run();
      
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, BPM);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V4, SpO2);
      

      Serial.println(Amp);
      Serial.println(angleChange);

      Serial.print("Heart rate:");
      Serial.print(BPM);
      Serial.print(" bpm / SpO2:");
      Serial.print(SpO2);
      Serial.println(" %");

      tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

Now I added GPS, so that I can track the location too. And GPS is working along with accelerometer but Pulse oximeter sensor is not working - Output from that is 0 and the rest of the sensors are producing the expected outputs. Program for that is given below

```
#include <TinyGPSPlus.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <Blynk.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>

char auth[] = "******************";   

// For GPS sensor
float latitude , longitude;
String  latitude_string , longitiude_string;
TinyGPSPlus gps;
WidgetMap myMap(V0);
HardwareSerial SerialGPS(2);

// For Pulse sensor
PulseOximeter pox;
float BPM, SpO2;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

// For Accelerometer sensor
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
int16_t accelX, accelY, accelZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
float gForceX, gForceY, gForceZ,rotX, rotY, rotZ;

void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat Detected!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin("TP-Link", "***********");

  // Wait for wifi to be connected
  uint32_t notConnectedCounter = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Wifi connecting...");
      notConnectedCounter++;
      if(notConnectedCounter > 50) { // Reset board if not connected after 5s
          Serial.println("Resetting due to Wifi not connecting...");
          ESP.restart();
      }
  }
  Serial.print("Wifi connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  Blynk.begin(auth,"TP-Link", "*********");

  // Pulse oximeter setup
  Serial.println("Initializing Pulse Oximeter..");
 
    if (!pox.begin())
    {
         Serial.println("FAILED");
         for(;;);
    }
    else
    {
         Serial.println("SUCCESS");
         pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
    }
 
    // The default current for the IR LED is 50mA and it could be changed by uncommenting the following line.
        pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
        
  // Accelerometer setup
  Wire1.begin(32,33,100000); 
  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire1.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire1.endTransmission(true);

 // GPS Setup
 SerialGPS.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17);
}

void loop()
{

  // Reading data from Accelerometer sensor

  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire1.endTransmission(false);
  Wire1.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  accelX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  accelY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  accelZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)

  gyroX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  gyroY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  gyroZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();

  gForceX = (accelX-2050) / 16384.0;
  gForceY = (accelY-77) / 16384.0; 
  gForceZ = (accelZ-1947) / 16384.0;

  rotX = (gyroX+270) / 131.0;
  rotY = (gyroY-351) / 131.0; 
  rotZ = (gyroZ+136) / 131.0;

  // calculating Amplitute vactor for 3 axis
  float Raw_Amp = pow(pow(gForceX,2)+pow(gForceY,2)+pow(gForceZ,2),0.5);
  int Amp = Raw_Amp * 10;  // Mulitiplied by 10 bcz values are between 0 to 1

  int angleChange = pow(pow(rotX,2)+pow(rotY,2)+pow(rotZ,2),0.5);

  // Reading data from pulseoximeter sensor

  pox.update();
  BPM = pox.getHeartRate();
  SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();

  // Reading the data from GPS

  if(SerialGPS.available() > 0) {
    if (gps.encode(SerialGPS.read()))
    {
      if (gps.location.isValid())
      {
        latitude = gps.location.lat();
        latitude_string = String(latitude , 6);
        longitude = gps.location.lng();
        longitiude_string = String(longitude , 6);
      }
    }
  }

  // Uploading data to Blynk server AND printing data on serial monitor
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)
    {
      Blynk.run();
      
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, BPM);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V4, SpO2);
      

      Serial.println(Amp);
      Serial.println(angleChange);

      Serial.print("Heart rate:");
      Serial.print(BPM);
      Serial.print(" bpm / SpO2:");
      Serial.print(SpO2);
      Serial.println(" %");

      Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, 1, latitude, longitude, "Location");
      Serial.print("Latitude = ");
      Serial.println(latitude_string);
      Serial.print("Longitude = ");
      Serial.println(longitiude_string);

      tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```

Will you please help me with this. What's wrong with the program.

Comment: The answer is : you have reached the limits of the "arduino" style programming. Now you need to learn how to use tasks, interrupts and RTOS-es

Comment: @0___________   No instant solution? In 2 days I have to submit the project along with documentation and presentation

Comment: See [this article](https://www.teachmemicro.com/max30100-arduino-heart-rate-sensor/) on "The Painful MAX30100 Arduino Module" section. Also, MAX30100 is quite picky on the clock speed, it needs to maintain at 100kHz, all those could contribute to the problem you are facing.